# Garbage disposal not turning on with on/off switch. Water in sink draining in dishwasher.

Tags: electrical, drainage, dishwasher, garbage-disposal, kitchen-sink

My garbage disposal is not coming on and water from the sink is draining in the dishwasher. Do I need an electrician?

Comment: `water from the sink is draining in the dishwasher` I think you might need a plumber instead. It sounds like the line is improperly sloped. Water should not able able to fill into your dishwasher. Get a new disposal and have the plumber make sure the line slopes properly.

Comment: @JoyceGreen - let us know how you managed with your issue .. All fixed .

Answer (score 2):

Your Garbage Disposal and drain is backed up.

The garbage disposal is jammed and the overload has probably tripped.

Look into the disposal with a bright flash light and you will find it probably needs to be cleaned out. With the unit off - clean it out.  You might also want to clean the U shaped pipe - called a trap that is under your sink - it is VERY easy and if you do a you tube search [How to Clean P-Trap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gk8jkguFZV0)- you can watch a video on how easy it is to do.

Then after cleaning them you can Reset the overload button which is usually located on the side of the Garbage disposal (red button looks like a writing PENs push button) and try to run it.

All this should take you about 30 minutes including the video..

Comment: I think some of those disposals can be manually turned from below with an allen wrench to work through jams. Make sure the switch is off first!

Answer (score 2):

@Ken is almost certainly correct regarding the disposal jam as the main problem. However, `water from the sink is draining in the dishwasher` is a related but different problem.

With the disposal jammed from below, sink water will try to go out the side to the dishwasher drain hose. But the hose should either be connected to an an air gap (usually a plastic/metal thing on top of the corner of the sink) or the hose should loop up from the disposal several inches before dropping down to go to the dishwasher. This requirement is specifically to avoid dirty water from the sink going into the dishwasher! Since that is happening, you obviously don't have an air gap (it just wouldn't fail that way) so your dishwasher hose is not positioned correctly.

It may be that the hose was in place at one time and fell down, or it could have been installed incorrectly - but never caused a problem until now, the exact situation that this requirement is designed to prevent.

[Article describing dishwasher air gap](http://www.startribune.com/the-most-common-dishwasher-installation-defect/158293175/)

Comment: Yes you are correct this could be an issue - and I am sure many DIY installs as well as Pro installs don't do this. Especially to the top of the underside of the counter. Just a guess on my part - considering years ago I had a DW installed in a new home and I can tell you the drain hose was not retained at height.